# Gtk+: How to Draw Custom Window Borders Like Chrome or Steam

Tags: gtk, gtk3, cairo

I was wondering if it would be possible to draw (ie design) window frames with Cairo in Gtk, so that the Cairo API could be used to decorate the surface such as adding gradients.

How would I tone down GTK decorations and redesign them with something like Cairo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally on Linux window decorations (borders, title bar, close and minimize buttons etc) are drawn by Window Manager, which helps to maintain similar look and behavior amongst different windows.

However, application may signal to window manager that it wants to disable decorations provided by window manager and draw their own. In Gtk+, that can be achieved by calling [`gtk_window_set_decorated`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated) on `GtkWindow`, and then using Cairo to draw own borders.

Comment: Awesome, @el.pescado. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager). An example of a window manager (now obsolescent) that used GTK and Cairo to draw its window decorations was [Metacity](https://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/).

Comment: So then how does Steam and others like Chromium have this without completely writing a brand-new DE?

Comment: WMs were superceded by Wayland compositors IIRC...Mutter is close as you can get, but I can't see where the design lives in mutter wondow-wise.

Comment: Chromium, Steam: they give a hint to the window manager to draw as few decorations as possible, and presumably draw it themselves with their own graphical routines instead of using an existing toolkit. That works per application, though, which is different from making a custom version of GTK like you asked.

Comment: I edited the question - my theory is that if there's a way to get a desired result once, it can be replicated. If I can learn to do what they've done with those two apps, theoretically I could write a library to simplify and repeat it.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, it's much clearer what you are trying to do! You don't suck at questions. Asking the right question is half the work.

Comment: That said, writing a library to do what those apps have done... is really writing a UI toolkit like GTK all over again, but making a different set of assumptions.